# Whitespace in a current regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, whitespace

I'm currently using the following regex: `^[^&<>\"'/]*$`     and I would like to also add a validation where a user can't just enter a space in the beginning of my textbox. Any ideas pls ? Note: Spaces are allowed but not as the first element

Comment: Just add it to the character class: `^[^&<>\"'/ ]*$` or `@"^[^&<>""'/\p{Zs}]*$"`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply !! My mistake that I didn't explain myself properly...I meant that I just don't want the user to start with a space or leave the textbox empty and put a space only @soner

Comment: Give several valid and invalid input examples????

Comment: Then try `^(?=\\P{Zs})[^&<>\"'/]*$`.

Answer (score 1):

A negative look-ahead is the way to go here: `^(?! )[^&<>\"'\/]*$`

`(?! )` means match only if the next character isn't a space. Since that is right after the `^` anchor, that essentially means match only if the first character isn't a space.

Comment: Note that this way you only control a literal regular space. You may use `\p{Zs}` to control any horizontal whitespace.

Comment: I avoid the `\p` syntax except when absolutely necessary, since it isn't as widely accepted. In this case, it doesn't work in JavaScript, and the question stated the Regex was for HTML validation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option: you may allow typing any space (hard or regular one) by adding `\p{Zs}` Unicode category class to your regex.

To make sure you still can match an empty string, you need to use a look-ahead anchored at the beginning of the string (that is, you must use it right after `^` start-of-string anchor):

```
^(?!\p{Zs})[^&<>"'/]*$
//^^^^^^^^^
```

I strongly suggest using [verbatim string literals in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) to declare regexes as you won't have to think about how many backslashes you need to use:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^(?!\p{Zs})[^&<>""'/]*$");
```

Note that you need to double the quotation marks in these literals to declare a single double quote.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/BgHt8z):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^(?!\p{Zs})[^&<>""'/]*$");
Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("")); // true - empty string
Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch(" sapceAtStart")); // false - space at start
Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch(" sapceAtStart")); // false - Hard space at start
Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("space not at start")); // true - space not at start
```